# Commutation of kinetic energy operator with Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, commutator, second-quantization, anticommutator

I am basically trying to calculate current energy operator $\hat{\mathbf{J}}_E(\mathbf{r})$ by using Heisenberg equation of motion as
$$ 
-\nabla\cdot \hat{\mathbf{J}}_E(\mathbf{r})=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\hat{\rho}_E] \tag{1}
$$
here $$H=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int{d\mathbf{r} \left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right) }=\int d\mathbf{r}\hat{\rho}_E$$ and $$\hat{\rho}_E=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right)$$ is energy density operator (the same thing is done in [arXiv:1502.00347](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00347)).

Now, I want to evaluate the commutator $[H,\hat{\rho}_E]$:
$$
\begin{align}
[H,\hat{\rho}_E]&=\left[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int{d\mathbf{r} \left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right) },\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right)\right] \\
&=\frac{\hbar^4}{4m^2}\int{d\mathbf{r} }
\left[\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right) ,\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right)\right]\\
&=\frac{\hbar^4}{4m^2}\int{d\mathbf{r}
\left\{
\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left( \nabla^2 \left[\Psi(\mathbf{r}) ,\Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right] \right) \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right)
+\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot   \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right)  \nabla^2\left( \left[\Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) , \Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right]\right)
\right\}
}
\end{align}
$$
use commutation relation
$$[\Psi(\mathbf r) ,\Psi(\mathbf r') ^\dagger]=\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf r-\mathbf r').$$
$$
\begin{align}
[H,\hat{\rho}_E]&=\frac{\hbar^4}{4m^2}\int{d\mathbf{r}
\left\{
\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right) \left( \nabla^2 \delta(\mathbf{r}) \right)
-\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot   \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right)  \nabla^2\left( \delta(\mathbf{r})\right)
\right\}
}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
The commutator becomes zero. It should not be, as given in the above-mentioned article's Eq. $(8)$.

**Edit:**

Change argument of $\hat{\rho}_E$ to $\mathbf{r'}$. Now, we have $$\hat{\rho}_E=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\nabla' \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r'}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla'\Psi(\mathbf{r'}) \right).$$ And commutator becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
[H,\hat{\rho}_E]&=\frac{\hbar^4}{4m^2}\int{d\mathbf{r}
\left\{
\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla'\Psi(\mathbf{r'}) \right) \left( \nabla\cdot\nabla' \delta(\mathbf{r-r'}) \right)
-\left(\nabla' \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r'}) \right) \cdot   \left(\nabla\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right)  \nabla\cdot\nabla'\left( \delta(\mathbf{r-r'})\right)
\right\}
}
\end{align}
$$
The integration could be solved by using formula $$\int dr \mathbf{F}(r) \nabla^k (\delta(r-r'))=(-1)^k\int dr \nabla^k \cdot (\mathbf{F}(r)) \delta(r-r')=(-1)^k \nabla^k \cdot(\mathbf{F}(r))|_{r=r'}.$$ Solving only the first integration term from above equation:

$$
\begin{align}
I_1&=\int{d\mathbf{r}
\left(\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right) \cdot  \left(\nabla'\Psi(\mathbf{r'}) \right) \left( \nabla\cdot\nabla' \delta(\mathbf{r-r'}) \right)
}\\
&=-\int{d\mathbf{r}
\left(\nabla \cdot (\nabla \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r})) \right)  \left(\nabla'\Psi(\mathbf{r'}) \right) \nabla' \delta(\mathbf{r-r'})
}\\
&=-\int{d\mathbf{r}
\left(\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right)  \nabla'\cdot\left(\nabla'\Psi(\mathbf{r'}) \right)  \delta(\mathbf{r-r'})
}\\
&=+\int{d\mathbf{r}
\left(\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right)  \left(\nabla'^2\Psi(\mathbf{r'}) \right)  \delta(\mathbf{r-r'})
}\\
&=+
\left(\nabla^2 \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}) \right)  \left(\nabla^2\Psi(\mathbf{r}) \right)
\end{align}
$$
By the same method, we find that the other part of integration is equal to $-I_1$. Hence, total integration is zero.

Comment: My first guess would be it's an error due to using the same symbol, $\mathbf{r}$, for the integration variable in $H$ and the argument of $\rho_E$. I think you will then end up with something like $\nabla \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\nabla \psi(\mathbf{r}') - \nabla \psi^\dagger(\mathbf{r}')\nabla \psi(\mathbf{r})\ne0$

Comment: @BySymmetry oh yes. This is an error. I am confused that when we use $\mathbf{r'}$ argument in $\hat{\rho}_E$, do I have to change $\nabla$ operator to $\nabla'$ too? For example, is $\hat{\rho}_E = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla'\Psi^\dagger (r')\cdot \nabla'\Psi(r')?$

Comment: Yes, generally the nabla is assumed to be a derivative with respect to whatever the argument of the field is, so you should in principle also add a prime to the nabla

Comment: @BySymmetry I edited the question. Could you please have a look again.

Comment: So OP's 'kinetic energy operator' is the Hamiltonian density.